# Typescript error for Material-ui's CardActionArea component property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-router-dom

The Material-ui [Buttons | Third party routing library](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#third-party-routing-library) documentation states that we need to make an adaptor do encapsulate a `react-router-dom/Link` component into a Button. But doing the same with a `CardActionArea` (which is a BaseButton, according to the docs) gives the following Typescript error:

```
main.tsx:24:10 - error TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<LinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CardActionAreaProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CardActionAreaProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

14         <CardActionArea component={AdapterLink} to="/foo">
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The code works nonetheless. Here is a minimal example showing the error message on line 14:

*Note: there is an error on line 6 because Codesandbox is running eslint in a TypeScript file, so just ignore that.*

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-bash-w17bu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me and I do not have errors in TypeScript:

```
<CardActionArea {...{ component: Link, to }}>
```

Comment: When I posted this question, I was using Material-ui v4.0.1, which had a bug. On version v4.0.2 the bug was fixed but I was still using v4.0.1. I will mark this as the answer! Thanks

Comment: It works with mui 5!